# axiom builder is null error

Tags: jaxb, apache-axis, tomcat6, axiom

I am not sure whether it is relevant but We are using in our system axis2 and JAXB for xml parsing and soap for communication(On tomcat).
Everything works well, however, I receive in my logs the following debug message repeatedly after each incoming message and I am not sure whether we are missing something.

2013-01-30 23:41:44,727 [http-8081-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl  - Could not close builder or parser due to:
2013-01-30 23:41:44,727 [http-8081-1] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl  - builder is null

Does it make sense to anyone ? Was I supposed somehow to initialize the builder to configure it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, but a debug message. In can be safely ignored.